# Installing Shairport on Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux ARM

Tags: openssl, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I am having trouble building [Shairport](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/shairport-git-sysdcompat/) on a Raspberry Pi (ARM architecture). I run `makepkg -s` and get the following result

```
Makefile:2: config.mk does not exist, configuring.
sh ./configure
Configuring Shairport
OpenSSL or its dev package not found
Required package not found, cannot continue
make: *** No rule to make target 'config.mk'. Stop.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
```

It says OpenSSL is not installed, though I can confirm it by running `pacman -Q` and finding `openssl 1.0.1.f-1` in the list.

I am thinking the version of OpenSSL installed is not ARM architecture?

Comment: Is this an autools project? If so, you usually `configure with `build` and `host`. For example, `./configure --build=./config.guess --host=arm-linux-androideabi` (for Android). If not, please provide more details (like the output of a log file)

Comment: The project is in AUR(https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/shairport-git-sysdcompat/).  To my knowledge, this is the only log file there is.